# How to integrate wordpress blog into my rails web app at the same domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, heroku

I have an existing Rails web application at www.xyz.com. I bought the domain using namecheap and have deployed it using Heroku. I want to integrate a Wordpress blog at www.xyz.com/blog. I've never done this before and am confused how to go about doing this; should I integrate Wordpress using a wordpress gem in my rails app and deploy it or do I have to do something with Namecheap to integrate? I'm super confused and am not sure where to start. Any advice?

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting down votes on this question...any comments would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deploy a Rails application at Heroku, there is no way you can integrate a WordPress blog under the same hostname.

The major problem is that the Rails app is written in Ruby and WordPress is written in PHP. Ruby and PHP are two different languages.

My recommendation is to use a separate hostname. You can have your application hosted at Heroku under (www.)example.com, and host your WordPress blog elsewhere under blog.example.com.
This is quite easy and by far the best solution.

If can technically run a WordPress blog and a Rails app under the same hostname (I know for sure because I'm exactly doing the same for my personal site), but it involves some system administration knowledge (and I'm not sure you may have the necessary skills to perform such task) and you will need a custom server.

For your information, my configuration is based on Nginx as a front-end proxy. If the request comes a /blog location, I proxy it to the PHP interpreter. Otherwise, I proxy it to the Rails application interpreter (puma or unicorn).

This cannot be accomplished using Heroku, unless (but I haven't tried it) you use a custom build pack.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Simone. I'm reading that there is less SEO benefit if I set it up as a subdomain instead of a subdirectory. Have you used this before? http://rywalker.com/setting-up-a-wordpress-blog-on-heroku-as-a-subdirectory-of-a-rails-app-also-hosted-on-heroku It looks like it is possible on Heroku?

Comment: The complexity of the setup and maintenance is simply not worth the effort.